# trying to download document or file in webview

Tags: android

Here is my code but still give me the error "Unauthorized.You do not have permission for this action" I want to know why this error thanks. I have implemented permission but didnt work.

```html
public class TipsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION = 2;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_REQ = {
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };
    private static boolean verifyPermissions(Activity activity) {
        // Check if we have write permission
        int WritePermision = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (WritePermision != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    PERMISSIONS_REQ,
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION
            );
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tips);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView7);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl("https:www.example.com");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimeType,
                                        long contentLength) {
                if (verifyPermissions(TipsActivity.this)) {
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                            Uri.parse(url));
                    request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                    String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                    request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                    request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                    request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
                    request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition,
                            mimeType));
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                                    url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    dm.enqueue(request);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
//prompt user for permission
                }

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    }
```

Here is my code but still give me the error "Unauthorized.You do not have permission for this action" I want to know why this error thanks. I have implemented permission but didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

To write to the external storage, you must request the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your manifest file:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding where it denies the user if it is the wrong permissions. The problem with this is the "else" statement, since it just redirect if the permissions are wrong, and doesn't double check to make sure they're right. So, if the user got an unknown error, like to program stopped responding, or the connection faltered, it would allow the user to continue, since you don't double check to make sure they have the write permissions, and not just the wrong ones.\

```
if (WritePermision != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   // We don't have permission so prompt the user
   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
           activity,
           PERMISSIONS_REQ,
           REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION
   );
   return false;
   } else {
           return true;
          }
}
```

This should be:

```
if (WritePermision != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   // We don't have permission so prompt the user
   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
           activity,
           PERMISSIONS_REQ,
           REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION
   );
   return false;
}
if (WritePermision == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // Other code if needed
    return true;
}
```

It's not much of a difference, but it blocks unknown error requests from allowing the user to access the file without permissions.

Comment: Where can I add your suggestion like an example ?